# Android Spinner Background color and Triangle Color

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a spinner in my app which I want to have a custom background color AND custom triangle color.

Setting each is not the problem but the combination does not work. This is my current code

Layout:

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
```

Activity:

```
Spinner languageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
                                              R.layout.item_spinner_lang,
                                              new String[] { "DE", "EN", "SP" });
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown_lang);

languageSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
languageSpinner.setSelection(spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(prefLang), false);
//languageSpinner.setBackgroundColor(someColor); // if I use this, even the triangle has that color and vanishes
languageSpinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
languageSpinner.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

item_spinner_lang.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

The spinner is currently white. But I want it to be grey, the triangle white and the text also white. How it do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom background and style for the spinner:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item_drop_down);
```

`spinner_item_drop_down.xml`:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/SpinnerItemStyle"/>
```

`SpinnerItemStyle`:

```
<style name="SpinnerItemStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bgd</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
</style>
```

`spinner_bgd.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp">

        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_custom_arrow"
            android:tint="@color/gray" />

    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not showing a triangle at all :(

Comment: What does it show right now?  Did you replace `@drawable/ic_custom_arrow` or add a resource with that name?

Comment: Did you apply the style to your spinner in the layout?    ```<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/SpinnerItemStyle"/>```